# threejs change object and animating

Tags: three.js, webgl, gltf, fbx

My character is wearing glasses and I want to replace them with glasses of a different model.
The replacement part was successful, but the animation of the glasses part works strangely.
Animation used mixamo.com.

```js
    const glasses = this.resources.items.glasses2.children.filter((m) => m instanceof Mesh)[0]//.scene.children[0].children[1];
    this.char3.instance.traverse((m) => {
      if (m.name === 'glasses') {
        m.geometry.dispose();
        m.geometry = glasses.geometry.clone();
        m.geometry.scale(0.000263, 0.000263, 0.000263);
        m.geometry.translate(-0.03, -0.05, 0.02);
        m.geometry.needsUpdate = true;
        m.material = [glasses.material[0].clone(), glasses.material[1].clone()]
        m.material.needsUpdate = true;
        m.updateMatrix();
      }
    })
```

working img
[image]

error img
[image]

The direction of movement seems to be opposite. Is that right?
If yes, how do I fix it?

Comment: Maybe the glasses are attached to the wrong bone in the model?  I'm just guessing.  It looks like maybe they're following an upper-back bone or something, instead of a head bone.

Comment: @emackey Thank you. I think you're right. I only changed the geometry and material from glasses. Why is that?

Comment: At first, I tried to change only the geometry that Mesh kept the shape, but I changed the direction due to the above error.
There is skeleton in the model, and the mesh was added as a child to the corresponding headbone to make it work.
it works well.